# git-p4 migrate branches in different subdirectories

Tags: git, branch, perforce, git-p4

I want to migrate source code tree from perforce to git. The source code contains several dev branches scattered across perforce depot, not necessarily in the same directory. for example the structure is something like this -

```
//depot/dev/project/master 
//depot/dev/project/branch1 
//depot/dev/project/branch2
//depot/dev/sub-project/branch3 
//depot/dev/sub-project/branch4 
//depot/patch-project/branch5 
//depot/patch-project/special/developern/branch6
```

I went though git-p4 documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4 BRANCH DETECTION section and also similar articles http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/1395-git-p4-and-multiple-branches/.

I am able to migrate branches with history for those which are under immediate parent like

```
 //depot/dev/project/branch1 and 
 //depot/dev/project/branch2
```

What I am not able to achieve is how can I migrate all six branches together at once.

I tried running the migration on //depot@all level after specifying the branch specs, however it is failing since perforce server is huge, it gives either  maxresults exception or session timeout. Can somebody please guide how this scenario can be handled?

Another option I see is to migrate branches separately (one branch to one git repo) and then merge those all branches into a new git repo. I am not sure if doing this what will be impact/downside.

```
Thanks and Regards,
Amar Kumbhar.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Summary:**  It works, git-p4 is a great tool, very intelligent, comes with lot of configurable options. Multiple branches scattered wherever across depot tree migrated successfully.  We need to run the import at highest level (topmost) perforce directory that covers all sub-directories or branches of interest. For efficient operation, suggested to use ***--changesfile*** option, to explicitly specify changelists to be imported. Also use ***git-p4.branchUser*** and ***git-p4.branchList*** to explicitly specify branchspecs.

**Details:**  Here I am showing the settings that worked for me. There may be a better way to achieve the goal.

**Perforce depot structure:** (as mentioned in question)

**Perforce client:**  This is set at highest (topmost) p4 directory. This is very important, otherwise git-p4 may exclude changelists (restricted due to client view) as empty commits.

```
   //depot/... //myp4client/...
```

**Perforce branchspecs:** I created a single branchspec that covers all my branches dependency (parent/child) information

```
$ p4 branch -o test1 | grep "//"

    //depot/dev/project/master/... //depot/dev/project/branch1/...
    //depot/dev/project/master/... //depot/dev/project/branch2/...
    //depot/dev/project/branch1/... //depot/dev/sub-project/branch3/...
    //depot/dev/project/branch1/... //depot/dev/sub-project/branch4/...
    //depot/dev/project/master/... //depot/patch-project/branch5/...
    //depot/patch-project/branch5/... //depot/patch-project/special/developern/branch6
```

**git-p4 config items:**  Next, I setup an empty git repository and following config items.

```
 mkdir workdir
 cd workdir
 git init
```

(** perforce variables)

```
git config git-p4.user myp4user
git config git-p4.passwowrd myp4password
git config git-p4.port myp4port
git config git-p4.client myp4client
```

(** force to use perforce client spec)

```
git config git-p4.useClientSpec true
git config git-p4.client myp4client
```

( ** restrict to explore branchspecs created only by me)

```
git config git-p4.branchUser myp4user
```

( ** branch information, dependency relation, interestingly only last name (directory name in branch path) is required to mention, git-p4 automatically detects/pick what is required i.e. fully expanding the branch name )

```
git config git-p4.branchList master:branch1
git config --add git-p4.branchList master:branch2
git config --add git-p4.branchList branch1:branch3
git config --add git-p4.branchList branch1:branch4
git config --add git-p4.branchList master:branch5
git config --add git-p4.branchList branch5:branch6
```

**Changelists file:**  Next, I collected all the changelists, for all branches those I am migrating.

```
p4 changes //depot/dev/project/master/...  | cut -d' ' -f2 >> master.txt
p4 changes //depot/dev/project/branch1/...  | cut -d' ' -f2 >> master.txt
p4 changes //depot/dev/project/branch2/...  | cut -d' ' -f2 >> master.txt
p4 changes //depot/dev/sub-project/branch3/...  | cut -d' ' -f2 >> master.txt
p4 changes //depot/dev/sub-project/branch4/...  | cut -d' ' -f2 >> master.txt
p4 changes //depot/patch-project/branch5/...  | cut -d' ' -f2 >> master.txt
p4 changes //depot/patch-project/special/developern/branch6/...  | cut -d' ' -f2 >> master.txt

sort -n master.txt | uniq > master_sorted.txt
```

**Import:**  Finally I ran the import as below, I used "sync" and not clone.

```
cd workdir 
../git-p4.py sync //depot/... --detect-branches --verbose --changesfile /home/myp4user/master_sorted.txt
```

*On smaller depots  “  ../git-p4.py sync //depot@all --detect-branches --verbose   “  shall also work, in that case no need to create changelists file (earlier step)*

**Once import is finished, I am able to see git-p4 created all remote perforce branches inside single git repository.**

```
 git branch -a
  remotes/p4/depot/dev/project/master
  remotes/p4/depot/dev/project/branch1
  remotes/p4/depot/dev/dev/project/branch2
  remotes/p4/depot/dev/dev/sub-project/branch3
  remotes/p4/depot/dev/dev/sub-project/branch4
  remotes/p4/depot/patch-project/branch5
  remotes/p4/depot/patch-project/special/developern/branch6
```

**Then I created local branches from remote p4 branches**

```
  git checkout -b master  remotes/p4/depot/dev/project/master
  git checkout -b branch1  remotes/p4/depot/dev/project/branch1
  git checkout -b branch2   remotes/p4/depot/dev/dev/project/branch2
  git checkout -b branch3   remotes/p4/depot/dev/dev/sub-project/branch3
  git checkout -b branch4   remotes/p4/depot/dev/dev/sub-project/branch4
  git checkout -b branch5   remotes/p4/depot/patch-project/branch5
  git checkout -b branch6   remotes/p4/depot/patch-project/special/developern/branch6
```

**Next I simply added a remote origin and pushed the code into git repo.

Thanks for various pointers/help available in stackoverflow and online.**

Comment: This is super useful information. The documentation is so lacking in this kind of helpful example, and normally I would never thank anyone on Stack OverFlow, but thank you. This will save me huge amounts of time.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of git-p4 should not report maxresults exceptions, given that it will retrieve a maximum of 500 changes at a time. You can try modifying this value using the `--changes-block-size` argument, which might help you overcoming the problem you reported.

Here's the description of this argument, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-p4.txt):

```
--changes-block-size <n>::
    The internal block size to use when converting a revision
    specifier such as '@all' into a list of specific change
    numbers. Instead of using a single call to 'p4 changes' to
    find the full list of changes for the conversion, there are a
    sequence of calls to 'p4 changes -m', each of which requests
    one block of changes of the given size. The default block size
    is 500, which should usually be suitable.
```

Comment: Thanks for input. I tried setting --changes-block-size  to lower values like 100 and 50 even 5, since the p4 server size is huge, it still gives maxresults execption for some changes and my p4 admin complained my script trying to kill server making it slow/unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem before and in my case I had to find a workaround which is the one you described, I cloned each branch into it's own Git repo.

Even then individual branches had too many objects and the P4 admins were not willing to up the limit for requested objects so I had to also limit the amount of history I cloned.

For inactive branches I would only clone the latest version and discard all its history.

For more active branches I would keep from 4-6 weeks of history.

This means you have to manually figure out what the CL numbers are for the amount of history you want to keep:

From `git-p4` docs (section: DEPOT PATH SYNTAX):

`$ git p4 clone //depot/my/project@1,6 # Import only changes 1 through 6.`

Comment: thanks for sharing. I tried the range option //depot/my/project@1,6 this does not work for me since I need to run at top directory. this inspired me to try using   --changesfile <file>::
 Import exactly the p4 change numbers listed in 'file', one per
 line.  Normally, 'git p4' inspects the current p4 repository
 state and detects the changes it should import.   I shall share experience.