# Trying to Sync from Perforce to GIt, same product from different Releases

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I am trying to Sync from perforce to Git, same product from different releases to diff branches and i need to do it weekly. I dont need to do it other way round (git->perforce) and there wont be any changes on the git repo , it just a one way sync weekly

```
  (perforce)//depot/Rel1/cla  -> master in git
  (perforce)//depot/Rel2/cla  -> branch1 in git

 Is there any way to sync both the branches at the same time to git? 
 Is there any way to Sync from the label of each release to git?Instead of the release it self? 
 And as i need to do it weekly, is there way to do just the delta on every next scan?
```

I followed this [git-p4 migrate branches in different subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607393/git-p4-migrate-branches-in-different-subdirectories) to certain extent, but as the end folder names i need sync are same, i am kind of confused how to take it foward

```
   This is what i tried
    p4 branch -o test | grep //
    //depot/Rel1/... //depot/Rel2/...

   git config git-p4.branchList Rel1:Rel2

    client view - View:
    //depot/... //myws/...

    git init
    git config git-p4.useClientSpec true
    git config git-p4.client myws
    git config git-p4.branchUser myusername
    p4 changes //depot/Rel1/...  | cut -d' ' -f2 >> list.txt
    p4 changes //depot/Rel2/... | cut -d' ' -f2 >>  list.txt
    git p4 sync //depot/... --detect-branches --verbose --changesfile list.txt
```

After this the command is running infintely for hours and i had to kill it , after that i ran

```
       git branch -a
     remotes/p4/depot/Rel1 (Only Rel1 and no Rel2)
```

This is what i see in the log, for Rel1 it seems fine, for Rel2 it doesnt seem to look good

```
                   ^MImporting revision 1998133 (46%)Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', '-x', '-', 'where']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', '-x', '-', 'print']
    branch is Rel1
    looking for initial parent for refs/remotes/p4/depot/Rel1; current parent is
    Parent of refs/remotes/p4/depot/Rel1 not found. Committing into head of
    commit into refs/remotes/p4/depot/Rel1
    ^M//depot/Rel1/cla/depot/bb/cClient/uifclient/src/main/java/com/depotm/crm/isupport/site/popup/properties 100% (0 MB)^M//depot/Rel1/cla/depot/bb/cClient/uifcli
    ent/src/main/java/com/depotm/crm/isupport/site/popup/properties --> cla/depot/bb/cClient/uifclient/src/main/java/com/depotm/crm/isupport/site/popup/Cpro
    perties (0 MB)
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'describe', '-s', '1998144']
    ^MImporting revision 1998144 (48%)Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', '-x', '-', 'where']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@1,513']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@514,1026']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@1027,1539']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@1540,2052']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@2053,2565']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@2566,3078']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@3079,3591']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@3592,4104']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@4105,4617']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@4618,5130']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@5131,5643']
    Opening pipe: ['p4', '-c', myws, '-r', '3', '-G', 'changes', '//depot/Rel2/...@5644,6156']
```

Any help/guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have one of those huge repositories. Unfortunately there isn't a great solution for your problem, at least for now.

Using `--max-changes <n>` will still follow check all blocks of changes before stopping. Maybe using `--changes-block-size <n>` to decrease the number of blocks may help.

Cloning using `//depot/...@<n>,<n+1>` using the first changelist that affects `//depot/Rel1/` will at least allow you to test if the branch detection is working. But if I remember correctly, consequent calls to `sync` will fail (can't confirm right now).

Answer (score 0):

Use the "-v" option and it will show you what it's doing.

It will be quite slow if the round-trip delay to your P4 server is quite long.