# Migrate from perforce to GitHub

Tags: git, github, perforce

I just want to understand the Git_migration from perforce branches for on prime releases.

How to maintain branch segregation.

Should I have a single repository and maintain the different relese-versions as a branch for the same? Or we should have a separate repository for each?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git-p4 migrate branches in different subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607393/git-p4-migrate-branches-in-different-subdirectories)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bperforce%5D+migrate

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single repository and a branch for each version that's still supported. Mark all versions with tags.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, as these are the existing branches so tagging does not work for existing branches. I can have different branches migrated to perforce with a different branch, However, they will always be different form master and kind of permanent, so looking for some better approach.

Comment: And want to understand what is the industry standard for this kind of migration.